# Win32 window instances behaving differently

Tags: c++, class, winapi

I have created a window class using the win32 api. It creates a window, passing in `this` as a parameter so that I can create and grab the object instance inside the static window proc and pass this off to a non-static window proc. But this is leading to some issues with multiple instances of the class stored in a vector.

- With 1 instance everything works. The window is create, messages are handle and once the window is closed it is deleted from the vector.
- With 2 instance, the window that was created second is deleted as intended when closed. But the window that was made first, while going through the same `WM_CLOSE` message and setting the variable that tracks if the window has been closed that the second window did, doesn't maintain the changes once it leaves the window procedure. Almost as if the window it is changing is a different instance. If this is the case I don't know who that is happening as it should be getting a pointer to it's own instance and calling that instance.
- With 3 or more instances it gets even weirder. Just like with 2 windows, the window that was most recently created closes and is deleted as intended. But after that the behaviour is seemingly random. Sometimes closing the additional windows will behave like it does with 2 instances, where the values are updated inside the window proc but change back once leaving it. And then other times closing the additional windows can cause it to throw an exception in `RtlRegisterSecureMemoryCacheCallback` which I have no idea what it is or why it is not guaranteed to throw the exception.

My assumption is that I have done something wrong with the Win32 API and setting up the Window Procedure that means the behaviour is not as intended, but everything I have tried so far hasn't solved my issues. Any advice on this would be appreciated.

My code:

```
// Window.cpp

auto Window::InitialiseWindow() -> void
{
    m_instance = GetModuleHandleW(0);

    WNDCLASSEX wc = { };
    if (!GetClassInfoExW(m_instance, TEXT("WindowsWindow"), &wc))
    {
        wc.cbSize = sizeof (wc);
        wc.style = 0;
        wc.lpfnWndProc = StaticWindowProc;
        wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
        wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
        wc.hInstance = m_instance;
        wc.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
        wc.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
        wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject (WHITE_BRUSH);
        wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
        wc.lpszClassName = TEXT("WindowsWindow");
        wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

        if (!RegisterClassExW(&wc)) 
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to register class\n";
            return;
        }
    }

    SetLastError(0);
    m_handle = CreateWindowExW(WS_EX_LEFT, TEXT("WindowsWindow"), TEXT("Test Window"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                              CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, m_size.first, m_size.second, NULL, NULL, m_instance, this);
        
    if (!m_handle) 
    {
        std::cout << "Could not create handle\n";
        return;
    }
    ::ShowWindow(m_handle, SW_SHOW);
    ::UpdateWindow(m_handle);
}

auto CALLBACK Window::StaticWindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT wm, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) -> LRESULT
{ 
    Window* instance_ptr = nullptr;

    if (wm == WM_NCCREATE)
    {
        CREATESTRUCTW* cs = (CREATESTRUCTW*) lp;
        instance_ptr = (Window*) cs->lpCreateParams;
        SetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG_PTR)instance_ptr);
    }
    else 
    {
       instance_ptr = (Window*) GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA);
    }
  
    if (instance_ptr)
    {
        return instance_ptr->WindowProc(hwnd, wm, wp, lp);
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, wm, wp, lp);
}

auto Window::WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT wm, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) -> LRESULT
{ 
    switch (wm) 
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
    {
        m_open = false;
        if(!DestroyWindow(hwnd))
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to destroy Window: " << GetLastError() << "\n";
        }
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, wm, wp, lp);
    }
    }
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, wm, wp, lp);
}
```

```
// AddWindow() & ProcessWindow() function

auto Application::AddWindow() -> void
{
    m_windows.emplace_back(Window());
    m_windows[m_windows.size() - 1].InitialiseWindow();
}

auto Application::ProcessWindows() -> void
{
    std::vector<Window>::iterator it = m_windows.begin();
    size_t count = m_windows.size();
    while(it != m_windows.end())
    {
        if (it->IsOpen() == false)
        {
            it = m_windows.erase(it);
        }
        else
        {
            it->ProcessWindow();
            ++it;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You destroy the window but still pass to DefWindowProc after that.

Comment: After the windows are destroyed StaticWindowProc is never called.

Comment: Many operations, including `emplace_back`, invalidate pointers to elements of a vector. The pointer stashed in `GWLP_USERDATA` becomes dangling, any attempt to use it exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: The `emplace_back`  is only creating an empty Window there. All the initialisation code is done in `InitialiseWindow()` after being emplaced. Surely that would mean the pointer created in `CreateWindow(...) ` is consistent

Comment: As @IgorTandetnik said `vector` amuses that its contents is movable in memory. When it needs to enlarge it can allocate new continuous space and invalidate all pointers. If you want to manage windows in some structure, you should use pointers to your `Window` or better `unique_ptr/shared_ptr`.

Comment: You know what, I completely forgot about reallocation of a vector. I will be updating that as soon as possible.